# Firebase using compound queries

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop a chat application, so I have to change the order of chats due to the last updated message, for that, i create a compound query like that, the first one check if a user is in this chat room and the second one is ordering them according to last message date but the problem is it always shows a spinning screen which means I can't get data from that compound query. any solution suggestion for that?

**Query**

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('private_chat_rooms')
                        .where('roomId', arrayContains: global.user.id)
                        .orderBy('lastMessage.date')
                        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: can we see the streamBuilder error message? You can get it like this: `StreamBuilder(stream: //.. your stream, builder: (c, snapshot) {print(snapshot.error);...`

Comment: okay seems like i made a typo in indexing, thanks a lot!